# Can not run lan messenger

Tags: software-installation

I installed the program "LAN Messenger" from a deb file.

When starting the program I get an error message. I did installed `libicui`.

```
tanmn2@TanMN2:~/Downloads$ lmc
This is not a Canonical "designed" product.
Unable to load library icui18n "Cannot load library icui18n: (libicui18n.so.48: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64)" 
QGtkStyle was unable to detect the current GTK+ theme.
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the i386 package of `libicui`:

```
apt-get install <your_libicui_package>:i386
```

*Replace `<your_libicui_package>` with your package name.*

In your case (Ubuntu 12.04) `libicu48` and for Ubuntu 14.04 and newer versions: `libicu52`

Comment: @MaiNhậtTân Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). ;)

Comment: OH, sorry, i have no enough reputation :) 
Can you say to me the lib what I need install here? I replace <your_libicui_package> with <icui18n> and <libicui18n.so.48>, but no such file or directory. Thank you very much!